# Azure Task Group deployment through release - How to get Azure Function App deployment output url 'AppServiceApplicationUrl' for later smoke test task

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-functions, azure-deployment, azure-task-groups

I've created a task group which deploys an Azure Function App which normally in a normal release pipeline (not a task group), it gives you the option of naming this variable on the panel which opens on the right hand side:
[output variable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ieGhK.png)

But when an azure function app task is contained within a task group, it gives you no option to create an output variable.

I was wondering if theres a way I can capture that output variable so I can later use it as a variable in a later task within the same task group?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will find your variable but under slightly different name.

Assuming you have one FunctionApp in yout ask group you will get it via this variable

```
AZUREFUNCTIONAPP_APPSERVICEAPPLICATIONURL
```

To be sure please display all env variables. For Ubuntu you can add bash script with this command

```
env | sort
```

For more information please check this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-devops-docs/issues/6983#issuecomment-619254181).

Comment: @AdamBrittain Can you consider marking my reply as answer if it helped you?